# i want to crawl a website with python,but i meet a trouble . requests library is ok but 400 with Scrapy,the code below

Tags: python-3.x, redis, scrapy

i want to crawl a website with python,but i meet a trouble . requests library is ok but 400 with Scrapy,the code below

```
import requests

urls = "https://pan.baidu.com/s/1sj1JLJv"
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; 360SE)',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    "Accept-Language": "zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    'Content-Length': '0',
    "Connection": "keep-alive"<br>
}
print(str((requests.get(urls, headers=header)).content, 'utf-8'))


from scrapy_redis.spiders import RedisCrawlSpider
class baiduuSpider(RedisCrawlSpider):
    ...
    ...
    ...
    urls = "https://pan.baidu.com/s/1sj1JLJv" 
    yield scrapy.Request(url = urls,headers = headers,callback = self.first_parse)

    def first_parse(self, response):
        print(response.body.decode('utf-8'))
```

How do I fix this question

Comment: the first response.status is 200,the next is 400

Comment: Could you include the log with the initial success and the later error? Does the error depends on which URL you query, or it always affects the second request regardless of the URL used? Does the 400 response suggest that you have been detected by some form of anti-bot software?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but you won't succeed, because the page loads dynamically.

[image]

It is necessary to compile javascript on the fly - Selenium, Splash